# Water stream does not start for first half of tap rotation

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

The water in my bath sink faucet starts flowing only when the faucet has been turned halfway by 45 degrees. I would imagine water to start flowing slowly right from the start. Please watch the 10 second video here to better understand the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQb75.jpg

My contractor who installed the vanity and faucets said this is standard, but I find that hard to believe. What could be the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Take it up with the manufacturer. It's extremely unlikely to be the fitter's fault.

Comment: No, you need the first amount of travel to unseat the gaskets and seals.  If flow starts at the first movement *now*, then as things wear and you lose that tolerance, flow will start at -10 degrees of travel, and you won't be able to shut the valve all the way.

Comment: 45° may be a _bit_ excessive, but I've never known a single faucet to start the water flow immediately. It's not that far off from "normal".

Comment: How far do you turn it after the flow stops?

Comment: @SolarMike 45 degrees. @ others I don't expect flow at the first movement, but I've never had to rotate this much for flow to start. I'll try installing a different faucet and see if the problem persists.

Comment: So why turn it so far after the flow stops? Wgat is the point? Especially when you then complain about it..